# How to remove some categories in the love.plot in the cobalt package

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I would like to edit the list of categories of variables in the love. plot in my assessment of covariate balance. It is possible to remove some categories in the plot. My model contains many categorical variables with many levels hence the plot is so crowded.

Answer (score 0):

You can just not include those variables in the model formula. For example, if your variable `country` has too many categories, just remove it from the formula:

```r
love.plot(treat ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = dataset, weights = m.out$weights)
```

Here I'm assuming the variables you want to keep are `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`, your data is in a data frame called `dataset`, and your weights are stored in the object `mout` (e.g., the output of a call to `matchit()`).

Comment: what are the implications of excluding this variables in the model? I consider them important since I have used them in the prediction of propensity score. My aim is to improve readability of the plot

Comment: You can just put a comment in the caption of the plot mentioning that this variable was excluded from the plot and mention in the text what the largest SMD among all of its categories was. That way the reader can fully appreciate its balance without the variable cluttering your plot.